# Error when Setting transparent background for Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, background-image, transparent

I created an Activity (which has and YoutubePlayerView and other image) with transparent background using

following code:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.9</item>
```

After compiling, background is Dimmed correctly with `DimAmount = 0.9`. BUT, my VideoView also dimmed

with same dimAmount.

Full xml for my Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/other_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/ads" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How Can I fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: I can suggest u a better way for doing this is using a dialogfragment, all these functions u're trying to achieve is pretty easily acomplishable

Comment: I'm using DrawerLayout which require AppCombat Theme. I'm not sure there is any compiling error if i use it with dialogfragment. I will try, thanks!

Comment: There will be absolutely no issue if you use `DialogFragment` if you want i can provide an example also.

Answer (score 0):

Put this theme in the activity tag in your project's manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

it will make your activity completely transparent.

Then set the background of the root layout oht that activity in black with some alpha according to your requirement using this.

```
android:background="#33000000"
```

Change `33` as per your requirement.
It will dim the background things without effecting other views.

Hop this works for you.

Comment: is it still diming your video view?

Comment: can you please share the xml of your activity?

Comment: I Edited my Question, please take a look

Comment: If I add android:background="#33000000", background is a little dimmed, but if i change dimAmount (dim level) to higher  (Ex: 0.9). YouTubePlayerView looks like totally black

Comment: don't use your code, just try mine. for making it more dimmer change '#33000000' to '#990000' or for even higher change it to '#CC0000'
Don't use the style thing. just put the theme and background color as i mentioned.